# Receive Android NotificationManager Notifications from Non-System Apps

Tags: android

Is there a way to register to receive notifications fired from Notification Manager from non-system apps?

For example, application A sends an notification through Notification Manager, application B could then receive the notification, but not interfere with, and then process information contained within the notification.

I know this type of communication would typically be handled through broadcast intents, but the developers of application A have stated that given a lack of development resources, they are unlikely to add these broadcasts in any releases in the near future.

Answer (score 1):

No. Application B has no means to access `Notifications` raised by Application A or Android itself.

Comment: Hello @CommonsWare. Is this still true?  You answered this a very long time ago!  I see there's a new NotificationListenerService (api 18) and I'm wondering if there's anything that would work with api 15+

Comment: Other than NotificationManager, I am unaware of options here.