# Sending android "notifications" to a separate system

Tags: android, dynamic, notifications, broadcastreceiver

Basically I'm trying to get the "notifications" present in the notification bar somewhere else, or something similar in effect.*
Mind the `"`: I'm not really interested in catching and possibly messing with the original notification, I just want to know that it is there. There seems to be more questions around this topic, but mostly the quality is "I WANT THIS" with an expected "YOU CAN'T" answer. Maybe you (we) can come up with another option?

Things I have come up with, but that seem problematic are:

---

1: 
**Catching all send `notification`'s.** I don't think you can extend/override/change the current `notificationManager`. People seem to think this is not needed for non-evil apps. I disagree. But nevertheless I don't know any method that can accomplish this. Another option would mean to ask the manager for the current 'live' notification, but there is no such method I believe. Also the conclusion of these threads:

- [Global intents that are fired for all Android notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7797147/android-notification-broadcast)
- [Receive Android NotificationManager Notifications from Non-System Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818613/receive-android-notificationmanager-notifications-from-non-system-apps)
- [Is it possible for an app to replace the NotificationManager? (google groups)](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/11cfc6c249ff61a2?fwc=1)

---

2: **Catching Broadcasts.** This seems more doable, although not everything has a broadcast available. Apart from that last point: This would mean I would have to find out what broadcasts are available, and act on each one hard-coded. **How feasable would it be to let users add their own broadcasts? And how would they know if (and what) their favorite program sends out?**  (I mean: add their own the app should listen to, not add a broadcast itself obviously)
*This might involve something like an activity that catches everything for a certain period of time, and then you make sure you let your program send a notification, hoping it also sends something like a broadcast? Once a broadcast is identified, you want to act on that, but I don't know if you can change your behavior this dynamically.*

---

3: **Something completely different** that will let me send as many different types of information (user choosable in the end) to an 'outside' place.

---

* <sup>I'm trying to send all notifications to a secondary location (a watch in this case). I can make something for all sorts of different situations (SMS, phone, mail, twitter etc), but this means double bandwith and cpu (battery), and everytime I (or a user) wants to add another type of message, I need to code more.</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But nevertheless I don't know any method that can accomplish this.

Correct, short of modifying firmware.

> Another option would mean to ask the manager for the current 'live' notification, but there is no such method I believe

Also correct, short of modifying firmware.

> And how would they know if (and what) their favorite program sends out?

They wouldn't.

You are certainly welcome to:

- Define your own broadcast `Intent` structure for a broadcast saying "hey, if anyone out there has some sort of extended notification thingy, here's one!"
- Create one or more end-user applications that consume such events (e.g., routing to your watch)
- Document and evangelize your `Intent` structure, convincing developers to take advantage of it, either to broadcast such events or consume such broadcasts

Comment: Obviously that is possible, but not very likely to be adopted in my humble case. at your "they wouldn't": couldn't you make some sort of catch-all broadcastreceiver, that would catalogue all intents in a period of time, maybe several periods and show the overlapping intents. E.g.: start 'scanning', make the program do its thing (send yourself an email), stop scanning. Repeat. Check for intents that overlap. Dynamically add those. ?

Comment: @Nanne: "couldn't you make some sort of catch-all broadcastreceiver" -- fortunately, no, short of modifying firmware.

Comment: Hmm. Thanks. I'm not ready to completely give up on this idea yet, but have nothing specific to offer to counter your definitives :) I guess dynamically changing filters would be a problem too, right?

Comment: @Nanne: Well, you can't add new filters via the manifest. For broadcasts, you can register ones dynamically using `registerReceiver()`, but that requires some running component.